# How to source file from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I'm trying to source a file with an environment variable from my bash script, but it doesn't work.

This is the content of my script (`test.sh`), which is located in `~/scripts/test.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE_NAME=/tmp/source_file
touch $FILE_NAME
echo "export TEST=\"test\"" > $FILE_NAME
source $FILE_NAME
```

Then I use `alias` in `my ~/.bashrc`.

```
alias testScript=~/scripts/test.sh
```

But when I use my script `testScript`, it didn't set the environment variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't set environment variable"? What is your expected result?

Comment: When I try echo $TEST I don't see any value

Comment: Does the file `/tmp/source_file` contain what you expect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Environment variables only flow downstream in the process tree.

When you type `testScript` to a bash process, it creates a child process and execs `/bin/bash` or whatever is set by `#!`

Any environment variables set there remain only with the child process.  Export causes the variables to be copied to additional grandchildren (children of that child) that might be spawned from that child.

Nothing can copy back to a parent. You need to use source instead of running the file.  See Jonathan's answer.

You could try editing the files  `~/.bashrc` or `~/.login` to set enviornment variables you need frequently.

See also https://superuser.com/q/153371 and https://superuser.com/questions/18988/difference-between-a-b-and-export-a-b-in-bash for more explanation of `export` in `bash`.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use:

```
alias testScript=". ~/scripts/test.sh"
```

to source the file.  Or you can use `source` in place of `.`, but I don't much like C shells so I don't use C shell notations such as `source`.

Answer (score 4):

None of the other methods worked for me [`source /path/to/file` vs `. ./path/to/file`, alias, etc...], until, thanks to [this tutorial](http://bikulov.org/blog/2016/01/05/script-for-user-configurations-generation-and-sending-at-ubuntu-openvpn-server/) I found that using the:

**`#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang**

instead of the simpler `#!/usr/bin/env` one lets arguments pass on to the interpreter, which I think is the key here – see [this document](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#splitting) for more info.

In any event, if source commands in any form aren't working for you, try checking your shebang, that might be the problem :)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for and should be the accepted answer. Thanks!